# How to turn off Sorting in group by function as it's taking much resource & not required in my case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query for which I am doing "group by", but sorting is not necessary.

I am joining 2 table,

1. roleMstr
2. aclMstr
3. roleAclMap

'roleMstr', 'aclMstr' are many to many & stored in 'roleAclMap'

I am trying to fetch acl assigned to that role & are active (due to soft delete) & group them to  find assigned & total

When I checked in SQL Server Profiler, Sorting is taking 68%, & index scan 32%

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @RoleCode VARCHAR(20);
SET @RoleCode = 'CLN';
    SELECT am.aclGroup, am.subAclGroup, SUM(CASE ram.roleCode WHEN @RoleCode THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS assignedChild, COUNT(*) AS totalChild
    FROM aclMstr am 
    LEFT JOIN roleAclMap ram
        ON am.acl_code = ram.acl_code AND ram.roleCode = @RoleCode
    WHERE am.isActive = 1
    group by am.aclGroup, am.subAclGroup;
END
```

Query plan executor text [link1](http://collabedit.com/af9k6), [link2](https://pastiebin.com/5dbec6d4e434d)

I am counting how many acl are assigned to the 'acl group' based on 'role code'

I am getting the sorted column too.

```
roleMstr contains roleCode 
 CONSTRAINT [pk_rolemstr_rolecode] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [roleCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

aclMstr contains aclCode, isActive, aclGroup, subAclGroup 
 CONSTRAINT [pk_aclmstr_aclcode] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [aclCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[roleAclMap](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [roleCode] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [aclCode] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_roleaclmap_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [uk_roleaclmap_rolecode_aclcode] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [roleCode] ASC,
    [aclCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[roleAclMap]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_roleaclmap_aclmstr_aclcode] FOREIGN KEY([aclCode])
REFERENCES [dbo].[aclMstr] ([aclCode])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[roleAclMap] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_roleaclmap_aclmstr_aclcode]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[roleAclMap]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_roleaclmap_rolemstr_rolecode] FOREIGN KEY([roleCode])
REFERENCES [dbo].[roleMstr] ([roleCode])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[roleAclMap] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_roleaclmap_rolemstr_rolecode]
GO
```

If sort can be turned off through query somehow. The query will be executed within half of time.

[image: SQL Profiler XMLL]

Comment: Sorting is a necessity for a `GROUP BY` clause; SQL Server needs to sort the data on the columns in the group so that it can then Group them. Also, those % numbers don't *really* relate to how long the query takes and I would strongly suggest that the reason the query is "slow" is because it doesn't have an `INDEX` to help it.

Comment: Also, that query won't run as it stands. `GROUP` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), so you can't references an object called `group` unless you delimit identify it. It is, however, strongly recommended you do not use Reserved Keywords for object names.

Comment: To add to my point about the %: The % is more to do with the CPU cost, however, sorting data (that is likely already loaded into memory) is far quicker than having to read (and filter) your entire table. Just because a node in the Query Plan has a high associated CPU Cost doesn't mean that that is the bottle neck.

Comment: @Larnu, but you can see in the image, the column upon which it is searching it's already an clustered index.

Comment: @Larnu, i changed name hapazardly for posting, Willl remember your point

Comment: *"but you can see in the image, the column upon which it is searching it's already an clustered index"* No I can't, I don't have the DDL of your indexes and the query you've posted isn't your real query. Every column in the table is at least **included** in the `CLUSTERED INDEX`, but if you're filtering on a different column (in this case `is_active`) and that column isn't in the `CLUSTERED INDEX` (which I would hope it isn't, based on it's name) then the RDBMS has to scan the **whole** table. The image shows a scan, not a seek, meaning that the index isn't helping the RDBMS.

Comment: If you really need to help performance tune the above query, then post your real query, along with it's query plan (search "Paste the Plan") and include the DDL of your table(s) and the relevant indexes (both `CLUSTERED` and `NONCLUSTERED`). Then we can help you. That image has nothing to do with the query, as your query has **2** tables in it, and that execution plan shows 1; which has been blurred out. This is a just an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) right now, that we can't sold, as "Y" isn't a problem that actually exists.

Comment: ok. For 300 records, it's taking 33ms, with this I am using case, sum, over partition by. I though may be it can be faster. But, what you said about it sorts in in-memory(mostly). That was my query.  Where can I learn scan index, seek index, clustered, non-clustered index? I am new to this

Comment: Learning how indexes works takes time. I've been working with SQL server for at least a decade, and professionally for about 6, and I'm still learning. If you're willing to take the time to learn, I highly recommend Grant Fritchley's [SQL Server Execution Plans, Third Edition](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/books/sql-server-execution-plans-third-edition-by-grant-fritchey/). If you want to ask some questions on how indexes work, then [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @PSatishPatro . . . 33 ms does not seem like performance that you have to worry about.  If you have a real issue, then you need to post a question with more accurate information.  For instance, your explain plan does not read two tables, but your query does.

Comment: Updated my question. Have a look at it @Larnu

Comment: Your end question is still effectively *"How do I stop the *"costly"* sort"*. The Sort is needed for the `GROUP BY`; you can't stop it happening.

Comment: can you check the indexing pattern for seek you were asking. do I need to clster isActive too?

Comment: The code you've given only creates the table, `roleAclMap`, which only has a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on `id`; where are you other indexes and DDL or the other table?

Comment: other 2 tables has some other column not required in this scenario. And have only PK constraint, for which I have shared it at top of DDL of roleAclMap. It will increase the length, so I removed what is unnecessary i feel and provided constraint

Comment: The `CONSTRAINT`s have nothing to do with the performance of this query. Like I said before, we **need** the DDL of the table and the **indexes**, not the `CONSTRAINT`s, along with the query plan (not an image).

Comment: I don't have any extra. I used this much  to create table, and assign constraint. I haven't manually created any index other than what I have listed.  And, now only dound by googling how to generate query plan file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201786/discussion-between-p-satish-patro-and-larnu).

Comment: *" haven't manually created any index other than what I have listed"* That image says otherwise as it has a Nonclustered Seek.